# Scala pattern match on subset of random elements in a List

Tags: scala

Can anybody suggest a efficient style to pattern match on a subset of elements in a list

containsSlice expects order and does not work with an unordered comparator list

This is what I am looking for (an inaccurate syntactical representation to drive the point)

```
List(1,2,3,4,5,6) match {
 case x if x.contains(List(1,3)) => do something
 case x if x.contains(List(2)) => else
 case _ => do something else else
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).toSet match {
  case x if Set(1, 3).subsetOf(x) => println("do something")
  case x if Set(2).subsetOf(x) => println("something else")
  case _ => println("another thing")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can live without the pattern-match,

a single "subset of elements in a list" can be identified by checking if each element in the subset is contained in the list, like such:

```
if( List(3,1).forall( List(1,2,3,4,5,6).contains(_) ) ) println("do something")
```

Comment: Your answer will fare better if you explain what your code is doing and why it's an improvement.

Comment: Edited my answer.  Question seemed to suggest there were two problems: how to identify a subset and how to pattern-match multiple subsets.  Hope my answer helps :)

Answer (score 1):

you mean something like this? :

```
def [X]containsSubset(li:List[X],li2:List[X]) =
  li2 match {
    case Nil => true
    case hd::_ =>  li.contains(hd) && containsSubset(li,tl)
  }
```